# how to fill AutoCompleteTextView from SQLite Database

Tags: android, sqlite, contacts, autocompletetextview

I am trying to design a application for android in which, I have stored all the contacts of the phone in SQLite database and i want that the suggestion in `AutoCompleteTextView` should be filled from the database. Please tell me how can i achieve my target?

Comment: Where did you get stuck?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get an instance of `CursorAdapter`, then set it as the adapter of your `AutoCompleteTextView`.

Answer (score 2):

use this to bind array to AutoCompleteTextView..you first get the values from sqlitedatabase and store in to String Array..

```
myAutoComplete.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, item));
```

Answer (score 1):

You just have to bind your array of data which you are getting from the database to autocomplete like this-

```
AutoCompletetext.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, data));
```